# Authorization request header OAuth 2.0

Tags: android, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement OAuth 2.0 on a project I am working on. I am able to authenicate with the authenication server however I am having problems with the resource server. We are using a MAC token([spec](http://tools.ietf.org/pdf/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-http-mac-00.pdf)). You can see in 3.1 of the spec that I need to send a Authorization request header which includes the following. I can't make any sense of that. Can somebody show me what I am suppose to do here?

```
credentials = "MAC" [ RWS 1#param ]
param = id /
nonce /
body-hash /
ext /
mac
id = "id" "=" <"> plain-string <">
nonce = "nonce" "=" <"> 1*DIGIT ":" plain-string <">
body-hash = "bodyhash" "=" <"> plain-string <">
ext = "ext" "=" <"> plain-string <">
mac = "mac" "=" <"> plain-string <">
plain-string = 1*( %x20-21 / %x23-5B / %x5D-7E )
```

### UPDATE

I feel I am getting somewhere but feel like I am still so far from solving this problem.

So I am building something like the following

```
StringBuilder header = new StringBuilder("MAC ").append("id=\"").append(sharedPrefs.getString(Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN, "error")).append("\",nonce=\"").append(createNonce()).
                append("\",bodyhash=\"").append(bodyHash).append("\",mac=\"").append(mac).append("\"");
```

I calculate the body hash like so

```
public static String SHA256(String text) throws  UnsupportedEncodingException  { 
        MessageDigest md = null;
        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] shahash = new byte[40];
        md.update(text.getBytes("iso-8859-1"), 0, text.length());
        shahash = md.digest();
        return Base64.encodeToString(shahash, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

And the mac like this

```
private String hmacSHA256(String data) throws Exception {
    String key = sharedPrefs.getString(Constants.SECRET, "error");
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA256");
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    mac.init(secretKey);
    byte[] hmacData = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    //Log.i(TAG, "BYTE ARRAY TO STRING: " + Base64.encodeToString(hmacData, Base64.DEFAULT));
    String value = Base64.encodeToString(hmacData, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return value;
}
```

I am having problems as the server just doesn't respond. This is really driving me crazy, I can't image that this documentation is clear to anybody.

Answer (score 1):

you need to be aware that the *[MAC access authentication scheme](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-http-mac)* is an **extension** of the oauth2 protocol, similar to the *HTTP Basic access*, but optional, so there is no need to implement this in every resource server.

So if you make an *unauthenticated request* and the *resource server* respond something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 
WWW-Authenticate: MAC
```

The `MAC`, means that you are *allowed to use this scheme* of authentication.

The most common authentication scheme implemented nowadays for oauth2-based resource servers is: [bearer](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer).

---

If you still have concerns about how to implement this spec, there is an [excelent source for Android](https://github.com/Xotan/OAuth2Android) on Github to accomplish it. And probably the java class you need is [this](https://github.com/Xotan/OAuth2Android/blob/master/src/org/gerstner/oauth2android/token/MacTokenTypeDefinition.java).

Have fun!

Comment: the server team has implemented mac tokens not bearer tokens. tho

Comment: just to be clear for anybody working with that library in the future, the mac token part is not fully working